# Dynamic Element Names

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I want to transform an XML document. The source XML looks like this:

```
<svc:ElementList>
    <svc:Element>
        <Year>2007</Year>
    </svc:Element>
    <svc:Element>
        <Year>2006</Year>
    </svc:Element>
    <svc:Element>
        <Year>2005</Year>
    </svc:Element>
</svc:ElementList>
```

I want to turn that into:

```
<ElementList>
    <NewTag2007/>
    <NewTag2006/>
    <NewTag2005/>
</ElementList>
```

The following line of code isn't working:

```
<xsl:element name="{concat('NewTag',Element/Year)}"/>
```

The output is a series of elements that look like this: **< NewTag >**. (Without the spaces...)

**"//Element/Year"**, **"./Element/Year"**, and **"//svc:Element/Year"** don't work either. One complication is that the "Element" tag is in the "svc" namespace while the "Year" tag is in the default namespace.

So anyway, am I facing a namespace issue or am I mis-using the "concat()" function?

Comment: Glad, that the solution works. But generally I would recommend, to NOT create tag names during runtime on the fly (though it works!). I understand the xml TAG structure in a more static way. My solution would be: Take a static XML Tag like <element year="2007"> with such an attribute. You can still access it with XSLT and XPath with "element[year="2007"]. So you neither lose flexibility, but gain security and consistency... Just a thoúght.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably namespace issues and maybe one with current context. For source (with added namespace declaration to make it well-formed xml)

```
<svc:ElementList xmlns:svc="svc">
  <svc:Element>
    <Year>2007</Year>
  </svc:Element>
  <svc:Element>
    <Year>2006</Year>
  </svc:Element>
  <svc:Element>
    <Year>2005</Year>
  </svc:Element>
</svc:ElementList>
```

the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:svc="svc"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="svc:ElementList">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="svc:Element">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('NewTag', Year)}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will give you the output you need. Note that `svc:Element` needs to be selected using namespace prefixed and that the context when generating the new tags is `svc:Element`, not `svc:ElementList`.

Comment: FYI, if you need to reference params in concat, use `{concat{'a',$myParam,'c')}`